# Displaying a part of a string

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I get logs from the api in the format shown below. How do I just display the part after the last `\n` and time. The digits are time. Can it be done with some array methods or would I need regex here?

`1645549901022 Running\n1645549901022 Process started\n1645549901022 START - Cloning repo\n1645549934999 Removed dumps`

The part that I want to display is just `Removed dumps`

edit: `\n` is getting ignored so I think I would need to match the last digits/time

Comment: Use the .split(" ") function to change the string to array and then get the last elements you want.

Answer (score 3):

One line:

```
const input = '1645549901022 Running\n1645549901022 Process started\n1645549901022 START - Cloning repo\n1645549934999 Removed dumps';
const output = input.split(/[\n(\d+)]+/);

console.log(output[output.length-1].trim());
```

Result: `Removed dumps`

Comment: Don't use vars. let/const is so much better

Comment: looks like \n is getting ignored. is there way to show anything after the last number?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
<script>
   logString = "1645549901022 Running\n1645549901022 Process started\n1645549901022 START - Cloning repo\n1645549934999 Removed dumps";

   arr = logString.split(" ");
    text = arr[arr.length-1] + ' ' +  arr[arr.length-2];
    alert(text);
</script>
```